# Python built failed on Solaris 10

Tags: python, openssl, solaris-10

I have used self-built Python on Solaris for years without any problem.
Recently, I needed to install a newer version of openssl because the existing version of openssl (included in Solaris 10) was no longer quite compatible with the latest security protocols (i.e. I cannot ssh from Solaris box).

So, I installed a newer version of openssl, first openssl-1.0.1l, later openssl-1.0.2. Using the newer version of openssl, I can ssh from my Solaris box again.

But Python puked when when I run a Python script with netowrk-x, which was fine with my older environment.

I recompiled the Python (2.7.9) and found out that I cannot build _hashlib and _ssl modules.

The problem was quite weird.
The relevant error message was:

```
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable section
```

(a summarized version of compilation log is attached at the end of text)

Two library files, libssl.a and libcrypto.a, which were generated during openssl installation seems not properly generated (at least for Solaris env).

However, I really don't know how to proceed from here.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Aki-

```
% make
running build
running build_ext
warning: ldd: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so: is not executable
building dbm using ndbm
building '_ssl' extension
gcc -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9 -c /home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -shared build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_ssl.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/_ssl.so
Text relocation remains  referenced
    against symbol          offset  in file
<unknown>        0x1198      /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o)
<unknown>        0x119c      /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o)
<unknown>        0x11a0      /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o)

....

BN_set_bit       0x1a90      /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_gf2m.o)
BN_set_bit       0x1c44      /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_gf2m.o)
<unknown>        0x4         /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0xc         /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x20        /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x1b0       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x1c0       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x1cc       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x464       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x46c       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x4f0       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
<unknown>        0x4f4       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bn_ctx.o)
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
building '_hashlib' extension
gcc -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9 -c /home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_hashopenssl.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_hashopenssl.o
gcc -shared build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/_hashopenssl.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7/_hashlib.so
Text relocation remains  referenced
    against symbol          offset  in file
<unknown>        0x6a0       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(tasn_fre.o)
<unknown>        0x6a4       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(tasn_fre.o)
<unknown>        0x6a8       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(tasn_fre.o)

....


i2d_ASN1_TYPE    0x6dc       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(a_strex.o)
i2d_ASN1_TYPE    0x70c       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(a_strex.o)
i2d_ASN1_TYPE    0x8d0       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(asn1_gen.o)
i2d_ASN1_TYPE    0x4ac       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(v3_conf.o)
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
building 'dbm' extension
gcc -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DHAVE_NDBM_H -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Include -I/home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9 -c /home/neko/gnu/Python-2.7.9/Modules/dbmmodule.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4u.32bit-2.7

....

Failed to build these modules:
_curses            _curses_panel      _hashlib        _ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

I did another attempt to find a solution and found a solution somebody posted back in 2013:
Posted by Tom Kacvinsky:
http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/PIC-code-on-Sparc-Solaris-td47300.html

In essence, you need to do two things:

(1) Run ./config with -fPIC

```
% ./config --prefix=<target_dir> no-shared -fPIC
```

This adds -fPIC (generating position independent code) to gcc options for library compilation

(2) assembled sparccpuid.S to a position independent code

```
% gcc -I... -D... -E sparcpuid.S > sparcpuid.s
% as -V -Qy -s -xarch=v8plusa -K PIC -xcode=pic32 sparcpuid.s
```

-xcode=pic32 is the secret source.

//

Following his instructions, I managed to build Python with hashlib ssl support. And, my python program with network-x is working again.

I don't know if his solution is optimal but it solved my problem. I don't know why openssl distribution hasn't incorporated his workaround (probably because no test cases to check this problem. no test case fails, no problem).

I'm glad an expert has stumbled upon this problem before me.